# Generally speaking, how much does the Incredible Hulk weigh?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

Once he transforms from his puny human form, how much does the Incredible Hulk weigh?

Comment: HULK NOT WANT TO ANSWER RIGHT NOW, HULK STILL CARRYING A LITTLE HOLIDAY WEIGHT

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Hulk_%28Robert_Bruce_Banner%29) lists different weights for the different forms.

- As Banner he is 128lbs
- As the Savage Hulk he weighed 1040-1400lbs.
- As the grey Hulk he was 900lbs
- As the merged, intelligent Hulk he was 1150lbs.

Comment: where does this added mass come from?

Comment: @releseabe - A subspace pocket

Comment: @Valorum: is that canon?

Comment: I believe the exact quote in the handbook is *"from some as yet unknown source"*. We do know that  Frank Pym gets his extra mass from "*An extradimensional source"* so it seems like that that's where Banner is getting his bulk from.

Answer (score 2):

One point of reference is Endgame, where he clearly overloads a Land Rover 110. The 110 can carry one tonne, so the Hulk in the film looks to weigh considerably more than that to make the suspension scrape on the road - I'd say 2-3 tonnes.

Comment: The 110 can, with standard spring suspension, carry nearly 1600Kg. With heavy duty springs, that can go up to more than 2000Kg.

Comment: Fair enough - either way it appears much heavier than the other quoted figures of ~500kg

Answer (score 0):

I am partial to the Marvel Earth-616 Hulk stats that list him as 7'0", 1,040 lbs.  This is also in-line with the way that the Hulk was drawn for the 1980s cartoon series.